# Change Filezilla user passwords with PHP SHA512 and Salt

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, sha, filezilla

We're trying to match our Filezilla Server 0.9.6 user passwords to those that the user chooses for logging into our site with.  All googling points to old solutions that implement MD5, but the newer versions use SHA512 and Salt.  The below code successfully updates the Server XML file, but the new passwords are not working after restarting Filezilla.

Does anyone have experience in this, and can point out where this code is incorrect?

**My Code**
From https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=39934

```
<?php
$password = "myNewPassword";

$seed = str_split("!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~");
shuffle($seed);
$rand = '';
foreach (array_rand($seed, 64) as $k) {
    $rand .= $seed[$k];
}
$salt_raw = utf8_encode($rand);
$salt_html = htmlentities($salt_raw);
$password = utf8_encode($password);
$salted_password = $password . $salt_raw;
$encoded_password = strtoupper(hash('SHA512', $salted_password));

// For Filezilla
$FzPass = $encoded_password;
$FzSalt = $salt_html;

$xmlFile = 'C:\path-to\FileZilla Server.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
$Pass = $xml->xpath("//User[@Name='TheUserName']//Option[@Name='Pass']");
$Salt = $xml->xpath("//User[@Name='TheUserName']//Option[@Name='Salt']");

$Pass[0][0] = $FzPass;
$Salt[0][0] = $FzSalt;

$xml->formatOutput = true;
$saved = $xml->asXML($xmlFile);
chdir( 'C:\FileZilla Server' );
exec( '"C:\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config' );
```

**Before the PHP execution  `Filezilla Server.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<FileZillaServer>
    <Users>
        <User Name="TheUserName">
            <Option Name="Pass">1ED89AFBA4FD8EF177EAAF21E6641C33FC870860D5F399CD9B0A79632B0F2B08B235DB7258DB2B6EB58402AF29A4C8491CC8F82ED9D2E74EABA8F7B240D0615F</Option>
            <Option Name="Salt">-Z5c@tci:e?E4E@H@(cq)/W1zDMs#F&gt;XsYd$M)0t#{/s,tc@]GJYf@{@T.&amp;O*5sF</Option>
            <Option Name="Group"></Option>
            <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">1</Option>
            <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
            <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
        </User>
    </Users>
</FileZillaServer>
```

**After the PHP execution**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<FileZillaServer>
        <User Name="producer">
            <Option Name="Pass">57AECC6BBCCC8EE5A73F0E362E2434DBF617EC2C85404205D881B1B7A2D303405789F8B42DFE61EDD7CF197700B66307E998054615C8A9A1CA5A9988029F0EAD</Option>
            <Option Name="Salt">P,]mk&amp;amp;4N;v3`#&amp;lt;e8S?oj[U=Ja$}Q6~:\Z1{HuB&amp;gt;bnI/&amp;quot;M-pDh.qFylKfd0|LgT*G</Option>
            <Option Name="Group"/>
            <Option Name="Bypass server userlimit">1</Option>
            <Option Name="User Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="IP Limit">0</Option>
            <Option Name="Enabled">1</Option>
            <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
        </User>
</FileZillaServer>
```

Comment: `shuffle()` and `array_rand()` are not secure. These are all ASCII characters, so no need for `utf8_encode()`. And you should be using `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `htmlentities()` though again, that shouldn't matter with all ASCII. None of those will answer your question as to why it doesn't work though!

Comment: Maybe it's a better idea to use an FTP server library for something like Node.js or Go, and implement custom authentication on that?

Comment: Filezilla is the defacto standard here, so no changing that.

Comment: @miken32  According to the original author of that code, it "works", so I'm questioning the premises and other factors of which I'm not aware of in matters like this that are out of my wheelhouse

Comment: Well, looking at the password hashing code [here](https://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla%20Server/trunk/source/Interface/UsersDlgGeneral.cpp?view=markup#l270), and the salt generation code [here](https://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla%20Server/trunk/source/Accounts.cpp?view=markup#l531) it certainly seems like it should work. Can you append a user account generated by FZ server to your XML snippet?

Comment: Will do...hang on

Comment: I'm curious how you got `&apos;` in your XML. I can't get `htmlentities()` to output that at all; I tried all the flags.

Comment: None of this is in my wheelhouse, so I'm trusting the original author - that answer is pure sorcery to me.  I tried changing it to use htmlspecialchars(), but that had no apparent effect.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't encoding things twice? `&amp;amp;`, `&amp;lt;`, etc is in the sample you just posted. I don't use SimpleXML so I'm not familiar with whether or not it automatically encodes strings.

Comment: I don't see how that would be the case.  The PHP code shown is the entire script.  Using PHP7.x btw

Comment: Oh...that &amp ,etc.  is what Filezilla writes to the file when the user account is maintained there.  The second XML snippet is the result of the PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML will automatically encode* XML entities, so there's no need to do it in your PHP code with `htmlentities()`. In addition, I've updated your code to include a proper random salt generator. Give it a try!

```
<?php
$password = "myNewPassword";
$salt = "";
while (strlen($salt) !== 64) {
    $byte = ord(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1));
    if ($byte > 31 && $byte < 127) {
        $salt .= chr($byte);
    }
}

$hashed_password = strtoupper(hash('SHA512', $password . $salt));

$xmlFile = 'server.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
$Pass = $xml->xpath("//User[@Name='TheUserName']//Option[@Name='Pass']");
$Salt = $xml->xpath("//User[@Name='TheUserName']//Option[@Name='Salt']");

$Pass[0][0] = $hashed_password;
$Salt[0][0] = $salt;

$xml->formatOutput = true;
$saved = $xml->asXML($xmlFile);
```

---

<sup><sub>*There are special characters (`&`, `<`, `>`, `"`) that need to be encoded so as not to be confused with part of the markup (not always, but it's easier to just always encode them.) These get encoded as `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&quot;`, respectively. Since there is a special character in the encoded value, you can see double-encoding happening by looking for things like `&amp;lt;` as we see in your sample XML.</sub></sup>